# Postgres: Can't free space because I have no space

Tags: postgresql, log

I have a Postgres DB that someone was brilliant enough to install in the log partition of my linux box.

It has a serious index problem, with indexes ballooning up to 50GB per. As soon as I start postgres, the log partition fills up to 100% immediately.

Now that I know the problem, I need to start Postgres to clean up the indexes. However, Postgres won't start due to no disk space, and I can't clean out the disk space without starting Postgres...

There's literally nothing else in this directory now except for the Postgres DB, so I can't free up any more space from something else.

Yikes! What do I do?

Comment: Since you mention the log partition, I assume other partitions have space? Move the database directory to another partition and start it up there?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen good idea, but the log partition has 175GB of space and all other partitions combined only add up to 40GB!